# Using pluck() helper function in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent, laravel-collection

I'm building a small application on `laravel 5.5` where I'm getting a list of multiple users with there information, from the forms as below format:

```
{
    "name":"Test",
    "description":"Test the description",
    "users":[
        {
            "value":"XYZabc123",
            "name":"Nitish Kumar",
            "email":"nitishkumar@noeticitservices.com"
        },
        {
            "value":"MFnjMdNz2DIzMJJS",
            "name":"Rajesh Kumar Sinha",
            "email":"rajesh@noeticitservices.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I just want to get the `value` key form the users array via `laravel collection` something like this:

```
$userIds = $request->users->pluck('value');
```

so that I can put them into query:

```
$user = User::all()->whereIn('unique_id', $userIds);
```

May be I'm doing most of the things wrong but my main motive is to use `laravel collection` or `helper` functions and make a cleaner code for this:

```
$teamData['name'] = $request->name;
$teamData['description'] = $request->description;
$teamData['unique_id'] = str_random();

$users = $request->users;

$team = Team::create($teamData);

if($team)
{
    $userIds = [];

    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        $getUser = User::where('unique_id', $user['value'])->get()->first();
        $userIds [] = $getUser->id;
    }

    $team->users()->attach($userIds);

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Created Successfully'], 200);
}

return response()->json(['message' => 'Something went wrong'], 500);
```

I'm still learning collections, any suggestions is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data that come from `$request` (form) isn't a collection. It's an array. If you need it to be collection, you should convert it to collection first.

**PS**. If you have multiple DB actions in single method, It's good to have DB transaction.

```
\DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
    // convert it to collection
    $users = collect($request->users);

    $team = Team::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'unique_id' => str_random(),
    ]);

    $team->users()->attach($users->pluck('value')->toArray()); 
});

// HTTP Created is 201 not 200
return response()->json(['message' => 'Created Successfully'], 201);
```

or you'll need something like this:

```
return \DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
    $users = collect($request->users);

    $team = Team::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'unique_id' => str_random(),
    ]);

    $team->users()->attach($users->pluck('value')->toArray());

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Created Successfully',
        'data' => $team,
    ], 201); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to get the value key form the users array via laravel collection

Just use `map` then:

```
$userIds = $request->users->map(function($user) {
    return $user->value;  // or $user['value'] ? not sure if this is an array
});
```

**Edit:**

if `$request->users` is not a collection, make it one before calling map:

```
$users = collect($request->users);

$userIds = $users->map(function($user) {
    return $user->value;  // or $user['value'] ? not sure if this is an array
});
```